# Pythonanywhere install and import new module

Tags: python, pip, import-module, pythonanywhere

I'm new to Pythonanywhere and want to install the 'soundcloud' Python module. I've opened up a Bash console and given the `pip install --user soundcloud` command.

It appears to have installed, as I see it in the list of modules when I used `pip freeze` in the Bash console. However, when I open up a Python 2.7 console and try `import soundcloud`, I get an error message saying that the Soundcloud module does not exist.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've installed soundcloud for 2.6, but you're trying to use it in 2.7.

From [the FAQ](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/faq/):

> We've included both easy_install and pip for Python versions 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2 (the default is 2.6, add -2.7 or -3.2 at the end to specify the others)

Comment: Read over that part several times but still missed this, thanks!

Comment: I refuse to admit that the reason I suspected you'd overlooked that was that I made nearly an identical mistake in a similar context earlier in the day. :)

Comment: may i ask what is the actual command as i have tried variants which dont work such as   `pip3.8 install --user soundcloud` ?