# PythonAnywhere: import mechanize gives ImportError, but pip gives "Already satisfied"

Tags: python, import, module, mechanize, pythonanywhere

I apologize for a newbie Python question.

I have a script that has

```
import mechanize
```

which gives the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mechanize/__init__.py", line 122, in <module> from _mechanize import \
ImportError: No module named '_mechanize'
```

I would think this means the module isn't installed or initialized, but when I open a BASH and type:

```
$ pip3.5 install mechanize
```

...this gives the error

```
Requirement already satisfied: mechanize in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888463/how-to-install-mechanize-for-python-2-7)  and [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461846/pythonanywhere-install-and-import-new-module)  The latter comes close, but I think I'm using the right pip edition.

Sorry for what I'm sure is awful newbie nomenclature.   I suspect there's a difference between mechanize and _mechanize, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General suggestion:   You should be using `virtual environments` as this prevents problems in packages by containing the packages within each virtual env. Far easier to maintain python module versions in this manner.

On a normal PC you may be able to fix your problem like this (but it won't work on PythonAnywhere):

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mechanize/
python setup.py install
```

then attempt to import again.

If that fails then try to do the following

```
pip uninstall mechanize
pip install mechanize
```

Comment: Thank you.  The first two recommendations didn't work, but creating a virtual environment and moving all the modules into that worked great.  Thank you so much.

Comment: funny this is, that last statement was a throw in at the end - lucky I mentioned it!

Answer (score 1):

By the way, on PA you should use:

```
pip3.5 install --user --upgrade mechanize
```

more info here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules